# How do I reuse the the same url segments in the same htaccess file for two domains?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I try to get the first set of RewriteRule for the first domain to be ignored when I go to the second domain, it will not successfully skip the 3 RewriteRule's and I will get a 500 internal server error, which is most likely the htaccess. I can get to the first domain without a problem, but I want the two domains to go to their respective paths.

```
# First Domain - Ex: foo.bar.firstDomain.com/content/video/1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.[^\.]+)(.+)(firstDomain)(\..+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(.[^\.]+)\.(.[^\.]+)\.(secondDomain)(\..+) [NC,S=3]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /template/firstDomain/home.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(content)/(photo|video)/([^\/]+)$  /$1/$2/$3/  [NC,L,R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(content)/(photo|video)/([^\/]+)   /template/firstDomain/landing.php?p_sContentType=$2&p_nContentId=$3 [NC,L,QSA]

# Second Domain - Ex: foo.bar.secondDomain.com/content/video/1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.[^\.]+)\.(.[^\.]+)\.(secondDomain)(\..+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /template/secondDomain/home.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(content)/(photo|video)/([^\/]+)$  /$1/$2/$3/  [NC,L,R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(content)/(photo|video)/([^\/]+)   /template/secondDomain/landing.php?p_sContentType=$2&p_nContentId=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

**Update:** I have updated the 2nd line of the htaccess file from RewriteCond to RewriteRule in an attempt to skip to the second domain RewriteCond and RewriteRule's. Still not getting the wanted results.

```
# First Domain - Ex: foo.bar.firstDomain.com/content/video/1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.[^\.]+)(.+)(firstDomain)(\..+) [NC]
RewriteRule !^foo\.bar\.(secondDomain)(\..+) [NC,S=3]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /template/firstDomain/home.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(content)/(photo|video)/([^\/]+)$  /$1/$2/$3/  [NC,L,R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(content)/(photo|video)/([^\/]+)   /template/firstDomain/landing.php?p_sContentType=$2&p_nContentId=$3 [NC,L,QSA]

# Second Domain - Ex: foo.bar.secondDomain.com/content/video/1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.[^\.]+)\.(.[^\.]+)\.(secondDomain)(\..+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /template/secondDomain/home.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(content)/(photo|video)/([^\/]+)$  /$1/$2/$3/  [NC,L,R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(content)/(photo|video)/([^\/]+)   /template/secondDomain/landing.php?p_sContentType=$2&p_nContentId=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: the possible reason of 500Error is S flag in conditions.

Comment: Better you check Apache error log and report the error text here.

Comment: @StarkeenI have added an update from my second RewriteCond to a RewriteRule. anubhava - I have nothing in my Apache error log.

Comment: domain name is not part of match in rewriteRule, change your rule to **RewriteRule ^ - [S=3]**

Comment: @Starkeen Well, that would be used by every domain. I want each domain to go to it's proper directory.